# Prove subspace with orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I really have no idea how to go about this proof.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Let $W$ be a subspace of an inner product space $V$.  Show that $W^\bot  = \{ v ∈ V | \langle v , w \rangle  = 0, \  \forall w \in W \}$ is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: vector v exists in inner product space V

Comment: The MathJax symbol is $\in$. Right click over the symbol to see how it is written.

Comment: Show that if $v \in W^\bot$ then $\lambda v \in W^\bot$. Similarly, if $u,v \in W^\bot$ show that $u+v \in W^\bot$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward exercise, so if you have problems with that you should reread the definitions of scalarproduct and subspaces.

The proof of your statement only requires the basic definitions of these two things. For the following I will suppose that $V$ is a vectorspace over $\mathbb{C}$.

1) $W^{\perp}$ is not empty since clearly $\langle 0 \,, w \rangle = 0 $ for all 
 $w \in W$ and therefore holds $0 \in W^{\perp}$. (Check the definition of inner product.)

2) If $x \in W^{\perp}$ then it also holds $\lambda * x \in W^{\perp}$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, since by the assumption that $x \in W^{\perp}$ it holds for all $w \in W$ that $\langle x \,, w \rangle = 0$  and by the defintions of the inner product we see that $\langle \lambda*x \,, w \rangle = \overline{\lambda} * \langle v \,, w \rangle  = \overline{\lambda} * 0 = 0$

3) If $x \in W^{\perp}$ and $y \in W^{\perp}$ then also $x+y \in W^{\perp}$, since for all $w \in W$ it holds (again by the definition of the inner product):
$\langle x+y \,, w \rangle = \langle x \,, w \rangle + \langle y \,, w \rangle = 0 + 0 = 0$

The 3 steps above proof your claim, I hope I could help.

Comment: typo: 1/ ...therefore holds $0\in W^\perp$... (missing $\perp$)

Comment: You're right, I fixed it. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

First you have to do these

1. $W^\perp$ is non-empty.
2. $W^\perp$ is closed under scalar multiplication; that is, if ${\bf
       v}\in W^\perp$, then  $\alpha{\bf v}\in W^\perp$ for all scalars
   $\alpha$.
3. $W^\perp$ is closed under vector addition; that is, if ${\bf
       v_1}\in W^\perp$ and  ${\bf v_2}\in W^\perp$, then  ${\bf v_1}+{\bf
       v}_2\in W^\perp$.

Then $\bf v$ is in $W^\perp$ if and only if ${\bf v}\cdot {\bf w}=0$ for all ${\bf w}\in W$.

Towards showing 1) holds, note (and verify) that  the zero vector is in $W^\perp$.

Towards showing  3) holds, suppose that ${\bf v}_1$ and ${\bf v}_2$ are both  in $W^\perp$.   We have to show that the vector ${\bf v}_1+{\bf v}_2$ is in $W^\perp$; so we need to verify that $({\bf v}_1+{\bf v}_2)\cdot {\bf w}=0$ for all ${\bf w}\in W$.  Towards this end, use the fact that $({\bf v}_1+{\bf v}_2)\cdot {\bf w}=  {\bf v}_1\cdot {\bf w}+{\bf v}_2\cdot {\bf w} $.